# Is It Acceptable To Ask For Descriptions of Boardgame Components?

Tags: discussion

It might be just me, but I felt a twinge of discomfort at the recent [Alvin & Dexter related question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/how-many-monster-cards-what-is-the-bonus-value-in-the-alvin-and-dexter-ticket-t).  Basically the OP just wants a list of the contents so he can make his own bootleg copy of the expansion.

This might be fine or it might be borderline unethical.  I wasn't sure so I thought I'd ask if anyone else has any strong opinions either way?  I don't want to encourage people not to buy (fairly cheap) expansions for boardgames if at all possible - games designers need to eat too!

Comment: I was the OP and can understand this perspective and will happily delete it if the question is one that causes issues on the site.  I can appreciate that it does appear like a way of getting something for nothing.  Equally, in my case, I have spent hundreds, if not thousands, of pounds on boardgames and certainly if an expansion works well I would not only buy it but I am likely to buy it for friends I know who enjoy the game.

Comment: @AlexC - I know your question was well-meant reasonable, and I answered it despite my initial misgivings.  Just a bit worried that if there were lots of questions like this on the site, it might start to give people the wrong idea!

Answer (score 3):

We may not know that someone is bootlegging it.  I've very often wanted a component list to first find out if I'm missing anything, and second to proxy whatever it is I may be missing.